# "Parameter 'self' unfilled" when using ".get()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Login / Registration code for an online course I am developing.

When trying to write one of the functions that `enter` the "user name" & "password", it seems like I cannot use `.get()` function because Pycharm shows me an error - "Parameter 'self' unfilled".

I already used it in my code for the `registration` part, no problems were seen.

My code (the part of the function that makes the issues):

```py
def login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("300x250")
    Label(screen2, text="Please Enter your Login details").pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify
    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1

    username_verify = StringVar
    password_verify = StringVar

    Label(screen2, text="Username").pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Password").pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable=password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text="").pack()
    Button(screen2, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=login_verify).pack()

    c_1 = username_verify.get()
    c_2 = password_verify.get()
```

I added c_1 and c_2 just to try and solve the issues but no luck so far (it marked me in pycharm in yellow the parenthesis of the both  `.get()` modules.

error I receive within my pycharm (before 'Run'):

[image: error I receive within my pycharm (before 'Run')]

error I receive within my pycharm (after 'Run'):

[image: error I receive within my pycharm (after 'Run')]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] don't make people go hunting for your error in a bunch of unrelated code. Please post the full error message, including the stack trace, in the question itself as formatted text. Do not post images, or links to images, or links to code. Check out [ask] and the [help]

Comment: Noted my self for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using `StringVar` properly. `username_verify = StringVar` does not create an object of type `StringVar`, it just makes `username_verify` the same as `StringVar`.

The proper way to create an instance of `StringVar` is like this:

```
username_verify = StringVar()
```

Also, your use of `StringVar` is completely unnecessary. The entry widget itself has a `get` method. You can reduce the complexity of your code by simply not using `StringVar` or `textvariable` at all.